# How much current can these diodes handle in real world?

Tags: high-voltage, high-current

I came across these diodes on ebay today and was very surprised! So surprised that I probably have read something wrong. So I'm asking you guys just to make sure.

Can these little guys literally handle 1000 Volts, and 10 Amps, as in 10 kWatts of power on their own? In my opinion they look too small for that.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a complete datasheet? I'm pretty sure that 1000 V AND 10 A at the same time are could not be sustained. Perhaps it can block up to 1000 V (as in won't be destroyed by a short 1000 V peak) and can handle up to 10 A, but not both at the same time. Also power dissipation is close to forward voltage times current and the forward voltage will be couple of volts at most, so you'll get dissipation of few tens of watts in the absolutely worst case.

Comment: What's the part number? Also that 1000V is the reverse voltage it can with stand not the forward voltage drop

Comment: If the forward voltage drop is 0.5V at 10 Amps, then that device is dissipating 5 watts.  Not impossible for a device that size, but unlikely and **probably** not recommended.

Comment: sorry my question was dumb, i had no idea what "forward voltage drop" was until I just did a big research on the subject

Comment: @AndrejaKo "*1000 V AND 10 A at the same time*" would imply a forward voltage of 1000 Volts, or an obscene reverse leakage current rating ;-) Just being pedantic here, don't mind me.

Comment: @Anindo Ghosh Yes, I agree!

Comment: It's worth pointing out that big axial diodes like that actually use the (heavy copper) lead-wires for heat-sinking. That's why many diodes have such large diameter legs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passing 1000V at 10A through a diode does not generate 10kW of power. The power dissipated by the diode would be the forward voltage drop times the current. Only the voltage dropped by the diode counts toward power dissipated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, some diodes in the package shown will comfortably be able to handle 1 kV reverse standoff, and 10 Amperes forward current, at a typical ~1 Volt forward voltage. The two values are not applicable simultaneously, the first is for blocking and the second is for conduction.

Adding a heat sink, a simple copper band looped around the diode body, would be recommended - The diode datasheet if you had one would typically tell you thermal dissipation ratings and required heat sinking for the rated forward current.

I have some unmarked high power Schottky diodes in a similar package that can cope with 15 Amperes sustained current flow in forward bias, and the real problem I'm seeing is solder melting and flowing at the PCB junctions every now and then.

Comment: Still ~10W of power dissipated. That is a lot.